# Update text field based on "title" attribute of a dropdown options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would update a `input` field (hidden in the first time) based on title attribute of dropdown options.

```
<form>
     <select id="selectbox">
         <option name="test" value="one" title="title1">one</option>
         <option name="test2" value="two" title="title2">two</option>
     </select>
</form>
<input id="description_field" type="hidden"/>
```

Comment: What is your question @Monak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use [**`:selected` selector**](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) to get `selected` option and use [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the specified `attribute`

Use `.change()` to invoke the handler initially.

```js
$('#selectbox').change(function() {
  $('#description_field').val($(this).find('option:selected').attr('title'));
}).change(); //to invoke the handler intially!
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="selectbox">
    <option name="test" value="one" title="title1">one</option>
    <option name="test2" value="two" title="title2">two</option>
  </select>
</form>
<input id="description_field" type="text" />
```

Comment: How can show field "description_field" only when a option is selected?

Comment: @monak83, Use `.show()/.hide()` based on the condition...

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
$("#selectbox").change(function() {
  $("#description_field").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("title"));
});
```

- Bind a change event to the select box
- Get the selected option with `"option:selected"` selector
- Get the title attribute by using `.attr("title")`